# Eclipse is crashing after enabling java security (Java Cryptography Extension - JCE)

Tags: java, eclipse, jce, java-security

Eclipse is crashing after enabling java security. I have added local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar into jre/lib/security folder.

I got files from below link :

Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

```
Debug options:
file:/Users/jkuria/soft/eclipse_downloads/eclipse 2/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/.options not found
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error initializing container.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:93)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:209)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:201)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:168)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.initWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:137)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:83)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: setSeed() failed
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:458)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$300(NativePRNG.java:329)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:212)
at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:209)
at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:190)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.computeNodeAddress(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:127)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.<clinit>(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:35)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:313)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:456)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following to the **vmargs** section of your **eclipse.ini**

```
-Djava.security.egd=/dev/random
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of `/dev/random` will likely cause start up delays in your Java application as `/dev/random` blocks until significant entropy to be generated.

In general `/dev/urandom` will be a more performant and equally secure source of randomness.  Because of Java peculiarities, the vmarg will actually look like:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

However, it is unclear to me why this property is required at all.  The accepted answer works but gives no indication as to why.  I'd be interested to know the cause of the exception.